# The method xxx in the type xxx is not applicable for arguments()

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am new to java, and i am trying to do a city planning project with Building class and city class. I get the error " The method isValidPlacement in the type Building is not applicable for arguments()" when trying to building a method for addStructure in city class which returns true or false base on the condition in the method isValidPlacement from the building class. And i am not sure why and how to fix it.

```
public boolean addStructure(int x, int y, Building structure) {
    // x & y are new postions 
    // Structure is a building object called from building constructor
    int posx = x;
    int posy = y;
    int w = structure.getWidth();//Building width
    int l = structure.getLength();//Building length 
    int layw =  layout[0].length;// City width (Building type 2d array Building[][] layout 
    int layl = layout.length;// City length
    String sign = structure.toString();
    
    if (Building.isValidPlacement() == false) { // Error: The method isValidPlacement in the type Building is not applicable for arguments()
        return false;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
              layout[i][j] = new Building(sign,x,y);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

IsValidPlacement method checks for two conditions: if the building is within city range and if the building overlaps an existing building.

```
    public boolean isValidPlacement(Building[][] layout,int x, int y) { //example 2x2 
    //x and y are position of the building where we wish to plant
     // call for the get width function to compare 
    int w = getWidth();
    int l = getLength();
    int layw =  layout[0].length;
    int layl = layout.length;
//step 1 check for within city  
    if (x<0 || x+w > layw) { // check if x is outside of range 
        return false; 
    } else if (y < 0 || y+l > layl) { //Check if y is outside of range
        return false;
    }                 // If the above cond. all passed then check if overlap. 
        for (int i = x; i < x+w ; ) { 
            for (int j = y; j < y+l;) {
                if (layout[i][j] != null) {
                    return false;} 
                }
        } return true;
    }
```

both functions should return true or false statements.

Comment: >>>   if (Building.isValidPlacement() == false) 
Hint: it happens here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this line -

```
if (Building.isValidPlacement() == false) { 
    // Error: The method isValidPlacement in the type Building is 
       not applicable for arguments()
        return false;
}
```

- the isValidPlacement method is called with no parameters although the method contains parameters. Pass in the specified params to fix the error.